# Are there any APIs for Careers 2.0?

Tags: feature-request

I am planning to create a blog widget which shows data from a page on Careers. For this, I'll need some way to get that data. This could be done using an iframe, but I'm hoping for other avenues as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RSS feed 'API' to get data. Example:

- http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed?searchTerm=ruby&location=seattle&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles